# Microsoft Office security settings: Which hive is better?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, macros

I am trying to check the status of macros in my home network. On my local system, I check for:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.x\Word\Security\VBAWarnings =

This I do according to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6 and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/diana_tudor/2014/12/02/microsoft-project-how-to-control-macro-settings-using-registry-keys/

I have also verified this after updating these settings with RegShot.

However, I also read online on Microsoft forums that these keys can also be configured from HKLM. Does any one have an idea as to which of these hives is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are. Typically, if a setting exists in HKLM it takes precedence over the HKCU entry.

HKLM also affects all users of the system. HKCU affects only the "Current User", all users have their own HKCU, hence it's name.

Comment: I agree. Then why this confusing documentation by Microsoft? They should mention this in the settings right?

Comment: Actually it is usually specified in the group policy description. But, you found documentation on how to modify registry keys which is technically bypassing the group policy editor.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2a16513e-5118-4995-a00d-0952e59b938a/does-computer-overrides-user-gpo?forum=winserverGP